# EXC_BAD_ACCESS app crash Objective C code = 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

The app crashes on reaching this code

```
- (void)setUniformsForProgramAtIndex:(NSUInteger)programIndex {
    [uniformStateRestorationBlocks enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
        dispatch_block_t currentBlock = obj;
        // error here is Thread:20 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address= 0x579fcea0)
        currentBlock();
    }];
}
```

Tried so  many things but still can't figure out what the error is please help me solve this problem...

Comment: `obj` - are you sure that you get a block?

Comment: show, how you declare `uniformStateRestorationBlocks `

Comment: currentBlock = obj; @Igor

Comment: If you show the crash and a symbolicated stack trace from where it happens, it would be easier to provide advice.

Comment: @Varun Kumar, I understand this, but are you sure, that `obj` is correct? Show how you set values for `uniformStateRestora‌​tionBlocks`

Answer (score 1):

Check contents of the dictionary.
Looks like obj is released which shouldnt happen since its retained when you add it. Put a breakpoint and check what value you get in obj.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `uniformStateRestorationBlocks` have a value that isn't a valid `dispatch_block_t` object or an object has been released in other place?

In general, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash is occurred by accessing a released or invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure, that values in `uniformStateRestora‌​‌​tionBlocks` is really a blocks.